# Getting error while doing setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2.2.3

I am trying to run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

but every time I am getting the below error.

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener
```

The same error is also coming while running **setup:di:compile**. I have also run composer upgrade, but no success at all.

Comment: I am pretty sure that composer update does not run properly. Seems some code missing.Please try to re-run composer update again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try `composer self-update` and `composer update` after it.